# VBA Loop and if statement issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with the following code. 
I want each cell with the value "long" in the column "U" to be copied in a new sheet.
But the code I developed only retrieves the first result. It does stop after "U6".
Can you please help me?

```VBA
Sub reportcrea ()

    Worksheets("TLM").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("U3").Select

    Do
        If ActiveCell.Value = "long" Then
           ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
           Selection.Copy
           Sheets("report").Select
           Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
           ActiveSheet.Paste
           Application.CutCopyMode = False


      Else
          ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      End If

      Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0))
End sub ()
```

Comment: If you were to complete this task manually, would you use Excel's built-in `Autofilter` function to grab all the "long"-matching rows at once and copy them all to the "report" `Worksheet`?

Comment: Hi Dan - Yes my idea was to add a second loop within the first one in order to perform another task afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I found a bug in your code in this line:

```
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
```

`Offset` takes two parameters, so it should be something like this:

```
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Select
```

Also, you should cancel CutCopy mode right after you paste what is in the clipboard:

```
ActiveSheet.Paste                 'Paste is done here
Application.CutCopyMode = False   'This is a good practice
```

See if that helps. Also, a screenshot of the `TLM` sheet would help us analyze the problem more accurately.

Comment: Hi Ahmad, thanks for your help but my issue remains. I think the issue could be linked with the "ActiveSheet.Range("U3").Select
" code as I only have the first result from the column "U". As I am new on this forum, I am not able to post the screeshot of the "TLM" sheet. sorry.

Comment: @user3929329 you can use any image-upload site and post a link to it.

Comment: @Ahmad `Range.Offset` has two _optional_ params: RowOffset and ColumnOffset. So `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select` is syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1):

First up, `End Sub` shouldn't have trailing brackets. When I copied it into a module it highlighted an error straight away.

Your loop is using `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select` twice:

```
   If ActiveCell.Value = "long" Then
       ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
       Selection.Copy
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'first Offset
       Sheets("report").Select
       Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
       ActiveSheet.Paste
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       Sheets("TLM").Select
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'second Offset
  Else
```

so you're only looking at every second row after each `"long"` is found.

I tested your code on 10 contoguous "long" cells and got 5 back in the `report` sheet. I couldn't reproduce your `U6` stop.

Comment: Hi Mark, I am looking to copy every row containing "long". "U6" was the first row where "long" was occuring. I insereted sevral "offset" function in order to try to go to the next "long" row.

Comment: The logic used will stop at the first empty cell below a `"long"` cell.

Comment: My file is 100 rows of either "long" or "short" without any empty cell in between. But the below code only retreive the first row with "long" and stop looping afterwards. Sorry if I was a bit unclear.